# Horizontal Scroll for UIView like as IOS concept in Android

Tags: android, ios, scrollview

I need to make an Android version of an existing iPhone/iPad App...

Now, most of it is already finished, but now I'm at the part where I'm stuck. I'm also not that great with Android, since I only started a couple of months ago.. 
(Please, No comments saying "Go watch tutorials" etc..  - I have. )

Anyways, Here are a few screenshots to clarify what I mean.

[image]
[image]
[image]

So as you could see, The middle part, with all the radio stations, is scrollable (Horizontal). Also, this is an infinite, so when you reach the "end" it goes to the front.. like: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2 .. Same when going backwards.

Also, these "views" are dynamic, and are shown when the radio is streaming, so basically, if I get the info from the API.

**My question is:** How could I make this in android. I've had a look at Horizontal Scrollview with pictures, just to test it out, but I figured it's not possible to make an "infinite loop".

Oh, I also have to add, that when scrolling, the current view, slightly fades, and decreases in size, while the other one (depending on scroll direction) loses it's fade, and increases in size.

Back to the question, I've also checked at a View Page Adapter (?) but I think that's not really the solution, since it won't be showing the ones on the side.. I think...

Anyways, If you could give me a solution on how I could do this, it'd be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: What about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289448/android-making-gallery-infinite-loop-of-images If you already have read it as you said, whats your problem with that solution?

Comment: check this : http://developer.digitalaria.com/devguide/gama/en/gama/carousel_android.php

Comment: use viewpager for proper implementation

Comment: Thanks guys, checking the links right now!

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar Really love how that looks like. Really organized, clean and looks smooth. I'll take a shot at that! Thanks

Comment: if i want to implement circular looping using this class is there any way it is possible if yes how Example : like if i have 5 images and i am on the last position 5 than i swipe right  than it goes to 1 position with animation and if i am on the first position than swipe left than goes to 5 position with animation what changes is required for this thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your xml file:

```
<com.signup.HorizontalPager
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"        
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </com.signup.HorizontalPager>
```

This is the Class you have to put in your project:

```
/*
 * Modifications by Yoni Samlan; based on RealViewSwitcher, whose license is:
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2010 Marc Reichelt
 *
 * Work derived from Workspace.java of the Launcher application
 *  see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.signup;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.VelocityTracker;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Scroller;

/**
 * A view group that allows users to switch between multiple screens (layouts) in the same way as
 * the Android home screen (Launcher application).
 * <p>
 * You can add and remove views using the normal methods {@link ViewGroup#addView(View)},
 * {@link ViewGroup#removeView(View)} etc. You may want to listen for updates by calling
 * {@link HorizontalPager#setOnScreenSwitchListener(OnScreenSwitchListener)} in order to perform
 * operations once a new screen has been selected.
 *
 * Modifications from original version (ysamlan): Animate argument in setCurrentScreen and duration
 * in snapToScreen; onInterceptTouchEvent handling to support nesting a vertical Scrollview inside
 * the RealViewSwitcher; allowing snapping to a view even during an ongoing scroll; snap to
 * next/prev view on 25% scroll change; density-independent swipe sensitivity; width-independent
 * pager animation durations on scrolling to properly handle large screens without excessively
 * long animations.
 *
 * Other modifications:
 * (aveyD) Handle orientation changes properly and fully snap to the right position.
 *
 * @author Marc Reichelt, <a href="http://www.marcreichelt.de/">http://www.marcreichelt.de/</a>
 * @version 0.1.0
 */
public final class HorizontalPager extends ViewGroup {
    /*
     * How long to animate between screens when programmatically setting with setCurrentScreen using
     * the animate parameter
     */
    private static final int ANIMATION_SCREEN_SET_DURATION_MILLIS = 500;
    // What fraction (1/x) of the screen the user must swipe to indicate a page change
    private static final int FRACTION_OF_SCREEN_WIDTH_FOR_SWIPE = 4;
    private static final int INVALID_SCREEN = -1;
    /*
     * Velocity of a swipe (in density-independent pixels per second) to force a swipe to the
     * next/previous screen. Adjusted into mDensityAdjustedSnapVelocity on init.
     */
    private static final int SNAP_VELOCITY_DIP_PER_SECOND = 600;
    // Argument to getVelocity for units to give pixels per second (1 = pixels per millisecond).
    private static final int VELOCITY_UNIT_PIXELS_PER_SECOND = 1000;

    private static final int TOUCH_STATE_REST = 0;
    private static final int TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING = 1;
    private static final int TOUCH_STATE_VERTICAL_SCROLLING = -1;
    private int mCurrentScreen;
    private int mDensityAdjustedSnapVelocity;
    private boolean mFirstLayout = true;
    private float mLastMotionX;
    private float mLastMotionY;
    private OnScreenSwitchListener mOnScreenSwitchListener;
    private int mMaximumVelocity;
    private int mNextScreen = INVALID_SCREEN;
    private Scroller mScroller;
    private int mTouchSlop;
    private int mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
    private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
    private int mLastSeenLayoutWidth = -1;

    /**
     * Simple constructor to use when creating a view from code.
     *
     * @param context The Context the view is running in, through which it can
     *        access the current theme, resources, etc.
     */
    public HorizontalPager(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML. This is called
     * when a view is being constructed from an XML file, supplying attributes
     * that were specified in the XML file. This version uses a default style of
     * 0, so the only attribute values applied are those in the Context's Theme
     * and the given AttributeSet.
     *
     * <p>
     * The method onFinishInflate() will be called after all children have been
     * added.
     *
     * @param context The Context the view is running in, through which it can
     *        access the current theme, resources, etc.
     * @param attrs The attributes of the XML tag that is inflating the view.
     * @see #View(Context, AttributeSet, int)
     */
    public HorizontalPager(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the scroller and touch/fling sensitivity parameters for the pager.
     */
    private void init() {
        mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());

        // Calculate the density-dependent snap velocity in pixels
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        mDensityAdjustedSnapVelocity =
                (int) (displayMetrics.density * SNAP_VELOCITY_DIP_PER_SECOND);

        final ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
        mTouchSlop = configuration.getScaledTouchSlop();
        mMaximumVelocity = configuration.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.");
        }

        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.");
        }

        // The children are given the same width and height as the workspace
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            getChildAt(i).measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }

        if (mFirstLayout) {
            scrollTo(mCurrentScreen * width, 0);
            mFirstLayout = false;
        }

        else if (width != mLastSeenLayoutWidth) { // Width has changed
            /*
             * Recalculate the width and scroll to the right position to be sure we're in the right
             * place in the event that we had a rotation that didn't result in an activity restart
             * (code by aveyD). Without this you can end up between two pages after a rotation.
             */
            Display display =
                    ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                            .getDefaultDisplay();
            int displayWidth = display.getWidth();

            mNextScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(getCurrentScreen(), getChildCount() - 1));
            final int newX = mNextScreen * displayWidth;
            final int delta = newX - getScrollX();

            mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, delta, 0, 0);
        }

        mLastSeenLayoutWidth   = width;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(final boolean changed, final int l, final int t, final int r,
            final int b) {
        int childLeft = 0;
        final int count = getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                final int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                child.layout(childLeft, 0, childLeft + childWidth, child.getMeasuredHeight());
                childLeft += childWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
        /*
         * By Yoni Samlan: Modified onInterceptTouchEvent based on standard ScrollView's
         * onIntercept. The logic is designed to support a nested vertically scrolling view inside
         * this one; once a scroll registers for X-wise scrolling, handle it in this view and don't
         * let the children, but once a scroll registers for y-wise scrolling, let the children
         * handle it exclusively.
         */
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        boolean intercept = false;

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                /*
                 * If we're in a horizontal scroll event, take it (intercept further events). But if
                 * we're mid-vertical-scroll, don't even try; let the children deal with it. If we
                 * haven't found a scroll event yet, check for one.
                 */
                if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING) {
                    /*
                     * We've already started a horizontal scroll; set intercept to true so we can
                     * take the remainder of all touch events in onTouchEvent.
                     */
                    intercept = true;
                } else if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_VERTICAL_SCROLLING) {
                    // Let children handle the events for the duration of the scroll event.
                    intercept = false;
                } else { // We haven't picked up a scroll event yet; check for one.

                    /*
                     * If we detected a horizontal scroll event, start stealing touch events (mark
                     * as scrolling). Otherwise, see if we had a vertical scroll event -- if so, let
                     * the children handle it and don't look to intercept again until the motion is
                     * done.
                     */

                    final float x = ev.getX();
                    final int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(x - mLastMotionX);
                    boolean xMoved = xDiff > mTouchSlop;

                    if (xMoved) {
                        // Scroll if the user moved far enough along the X axis
                        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING;
                        mLastMotionX = x;
                    }

                    final float y = ev.getY();
                    final int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(y - mLastMotionY);
                    boolean yMoved = yDiff > mTouchSlop;

                    if (yMoved) {
                        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_VERTICAL_SCROLLING;
                    }
                }

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Release the drag.
                mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                /*
                 * No motion yet, but register the coordinates so we can check for intercept at the
                 * next MOVE event.
                 */
                mLastMotionY = ev.getY();
                mLastMotionX = ev.getX();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        return intercept;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {

        if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
            mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
        }
        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        final float x = ev.getX();

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                /*
                 * If being flinged and user touches, stop the fling. isFinished will be false if
                 * being flinged.
                 */
                if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
                    mScroller.abortAnimation();
                }

                // Remember where the motion event started
                mLastMotionX = x;

                if (mScroller.isFinished()) {
                    mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
                } else {
                    mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING;
                }

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(x - mLastMotionX);
                boolean xMoved = xDiff > mTouchSlop;

                if (xMoved) {
                    // Scroll if the user moved far enough along the X axis
                    mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING;
                }

                if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING) {
                    // Scroll to follow the motion event
                    final int deltaX = (int) (mLastMotionX - x);
                    mLastMotionX = x;
                    final int scrollX = getScrollX();

                    if (deltaX < 0) {
                        if (scrollX > 0) {
                            scrollBy(Math.max(-scrollX, deltaX), 0);
                        }
                    } else if (deltaX > 0) {
                        final int availableToScroll =
                                getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1).getRight() - scrollX - getWidth();

                        if (availableToScroll > 0) {
                            scrollBy(Math.min(availableToScroll, deltaX), 0);
                        }
                    }
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING) {
                    final VelocityTracker velocityTracker = mVelocityTracker;
                    velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(VELOCITY_UNIT_PIXELS_PER_SECOND,
                            mMaximumVelocity);
                    int velocityX = (int) velocityTracker.getXVelocity();

                    if (velocityX > mDensityAdjustedSnapVelocity && mCurrentScreen > 0) {
                        // Fling hard enough to move left
                        snapToScreen(mCurrentScreen - 1);
                    } else if (velocityX < -mDensityAdjustedSnapVelocity
                            && mCurrentScreen < getChildCount() - 1) {
                        // Fling hard enough to move right
                        snapToScreen(mCurrentScreen + 1);
                    } else {
                        snapToDestination();
                    }

                    if (mVelocityTracker != null) {
                        mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                        mVelocityTracker = null;
                    }
                }

                mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void computeScroll() {
        if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
            scrollTo(mScroller.getCurrX(), mScroller.getCurrY());
            postInvalidate();
        } else if (mNextScreen != INVALID_SCREEN) {
            mCurrentScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(mNextScreen, getChildCount() - 1));

            // Notify observer about screen change
            if (mOnScreenSwitchListener != null) {
                mOnScreenSwitchListener.onScreenSwitched(mCurrentScreen);
            }

            mNextScreen = INVALID_SCREEN;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index of the currently displayed screen.
     *
     * @return The index of the currently displayed screen.
     */
    public int getCurrentScreen() {
        return mCurrentScreen;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current screen.
     *
     * @param currentScreen The new screen.
     * @param animate True to smoothly scroll to the screen, false to snap instantly
     */
    public void setCurrentScreen(final int currentScreen, final boolean animate) {
        mCurrentScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(currentScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
        if (animate) {
            snapToScreen(currentScreen, ANIMATION_SCREEN_SET_DURATION_MILLIS);
        } else {
            scrollTo(mCurrentScreen * getWidth(), 0);
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the {@link OnScreenSwitchListener}.
     *
     * @param onScreenSwitchListener The listener for switch events.
     */
    public void setOnScreenSwitchListener(final OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener) {
        mOnScreenSwitchListener = onScreenSwitchListener;
    }

    /**
     * Snaps to the screen we think the user wants (the current screen for very small movements; the
     * next/prev screen for bigger movements).
     */
    private void snapToDestination() {
        final int screenWidth = getWidth();
        int scrollX = getScrollX();
        int whichScreen = mCurrentScreen;
        int deltaX = scrollX - (screenWidth * mCurrentScreen);

        // Check if they want to go to the prev. screen
        if ((deltaX < 0) && mCurrentScreen != 0
                && ((screenWidth / FRACTION_OF_SCREEN_WIDTH_FOR_SWIPE) < -deltaX)) {
            whichScreen--;
            // Check if they want to go to the next screen
        } else if ((deltaX > 0) && (mCurrentScreen + 1 != getChildCount())
                && ((screenWidth / FRACTION_OF_SCREEN_WIDTH_FOR_SWIPE) < deltaX)) {
            whichScreen++;
        }

        snapToScreen(whichScreen);
    }

    /**
     * Snap to a specific screen, animating automatically for a duration proportional to the
     * distance left to scroll.
     *
     * @param whichScreen Screen to snap to
     */
    private void snapToScreen(final int whichScreen) {
        snapToScreen(whichScreen, -1);
    }

    /**
     * Snaps to a specific screen, animating for a specific amount of time to get there.
     *
     * @param whichScreen Screen to snap to
     * @param duration -1 to automatically time it based on scroll distance; a positive number to
     *            make the scroll take an exact duration.
     */
    private void snapToScreen(final int whichScreen, final int duration) {
        /*
         * Modified by Yoni Samlan: Allow new snapping even during an ongoing scroll animation. This
         * is intended to make HorizontalPager work as expected when used in conjunction with a
         * RadioGroup used as "tabbed" controls. Also, make the animation take a percentage of our
         * normal animation time, depending how far they've already scrolled.
         */
        mNextScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(whichScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
        final int newX = mNextScreen * getWidth();
        final int delta = newX - getScrollX();

        if (duration < 0) {
             // E.g. if they've scrolled 80% of the way, only animation for 20% of the duration
            mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, delta, 0, (int) (Math.abs(delta)
                    / (float) getWidth() * ANIMATION_SCREEN_SET_DURATION_MILLIS));
        } else {
            mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, delta, 0, duration);
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Listener for the event that the HorizontalPager switches to a new view.
     */
    public static interface OnScreenSwitchListener {
        /**
         * Notifies listeners about the new screen. Runs after the animation completed.
         *
         * @param screen The new screen index.
         */
        void onScreenSwitched(int screen);
    }
}
```

And put this code in your activity from where you want swipe images :

```
com.signup.HorizontalPager horizontalView = (com.signup.HorizontalPager)findViewById(R.id.horizontal_pager);


And then you can insert images programatically with arraylist like as follows:



MultiImageUrlArrayList-->This is Arraylist which contains list of images

for(int i=0;i<MultiImageUrlArrayList.size();i++){

LayoutInflater layoutInflater1 = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

final View addView1 = layoutInflater1.inflate(R.layout.home_profile_horizontal_swipe_image_list_item, null);

ImageView swipe_image_Add1 = (ImageView)addView1.findViewById(R.id.ImageView_profile_pic);

horizontalView.addView(addView1);

}
```

Comment: if i want to implement circular looping using this class is there any way it is possible if yes how Example : like if i have 5 images and i am on the last position 5 than i swipe right  than it goes to 1 position with animation and if i am on the first position than swipe left than goes to 5 position with animation what changes is required for this thanks in advance